# Compiling SASS files with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I want to use webpack so that it will automatically compile any and all .scss files in my /src/app folder into a single .css file without me having to explicity point to all of the .scss files / import them.

I am trying to use ExtractTextPlugin to do this but it does not seem to be working. Do I need to provide a more specific entry point? Are my loaders not configured correctly? Or is there something else wrong? Thanks!

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js"
    SRC_DIR + "/app/"
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5001',
        secure: false,
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: "foo.css", allChunks: true})
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        use: "url-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "start": "yarn build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build:dev": "webpack && cp src/index.html dist/index.html",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "3.x",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^6.0.0-beta.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.6.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch": "^0.5.7",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^1.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.4",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.42",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^0.8.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.59.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-highcharts": "^15.0.0",
    "react-list": "^0.8.8",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "3.2.3",
    "twilio-client": "^1.4.33"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> without me having to explicity point to all of the .scss files /
>   import them.

You can't do that, webpack is not like gulp or other task runner that you can just point patterns and it will apply transformations to them.

Webpack works with dependency graphs, and these graphs are going to start from your entry points. On each entrypoint it reads the dependencies and apply those loaders specified for each file extension. Webpack only knows the existence of that file, if it is imported in any file that is part of the dependency graph.

If you want to transform css the way that you described, i suggest you moving towards a more task runner library such as gulp.